# How to Split words and separate the ones with a certain letter?

Tags: java, split

In my program i want to take an input from a user, and separate the words with the letter "e" in them and concatenate them without any spaces or different lines. For instance, if my input was "Rob is a nice person" I want it to print "niceperson". This is what i have so far:

```
Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = kybd.nextLine();
String[] arr = s.split(" ");    
for ( String ss : arr) {
    String []ary = {ss};
    for(int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i++){
        if(ary[i].equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
            System.out.print(ary);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any tips or help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, it works like this:

```
Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String s = kybd.nextLine();
String[] arr = s.split(" ");
 for ( String ss : arr) {
     if(ss.contains("e")) {
         result.append(ss);
     }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a contains method? This is an assignment and we haven't learned about contains. I would like to use the methods i have specified in my code.

Comment: Sure, for learnings sake, just a hint first: Instead of the contains if, loop through all characters of the String (using `charAt(index)`) and only append the word if you find the searched letter.

Comment: what would you suggest be another way without the append method? (Sorry forgot to point out I don't know that method either...)

Comment: Just declare `result` as a `String` and use normal string concatenation like `result = result + ss`

Comment: @Merguez, even though your answer already had 2 upvotes, I gave you another one because your answers are so helpful and kind!

Comment: @BrettFromLA nice to hear, thank you very much. For years I was just a consumer of the solutions on that platform, i'm aiming to give something back now :).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way

```
    String str = "Rob is a nice person";
    String[] arr = str.split(" "); // split by space
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String i : arr) {
        if (i.contains("e")) { // if word contains e
         sb.append(i);// append that word 
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Out put:

```
   niceperson
```

Answer (score 0):

how about some method like string.Replace("e ", "e");
I assume you are using String static method, as I can see you are using Split

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\\b[\\w&&[^e]]+\\b)|\\s", "");
```